# Some Flash SWF files not loading at my server

Tags: flash, load

EDIT: See my comment.

Hello.

I just saw that some (only some) flash files (games) aren't loading in my website, but are in other servers. Most of the files do work.

For example:

(External) http://jogolandia.uol.com.br/arquivos/games/sokobones.swf

(My Server) http://www.plugb.com/files/games/sokobones.swf

It is the same file, but doesn't load at my server.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I have no problems in FF 3.6.8 on OSX.

Comment: I just discovered it works for most people, but doesn't for me. I'm using Chrome, Win7 64bits. I also tested with other browsers and with my laptop. With them it also doesn't work. It don't work for just at my host. At the other host it does work.

Comment: I discovered that the only browser that works is Firefox. Chrome, Safari and IE do not work for me. (PC + Laptop)

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the same issue and it's driving me mad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322551/swf-file-loads-externally-but-not-on-local-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there may be several Security Sandbox Violations looking at my trace output.

Comment: But why can't I view the SWF?